# GWT: How to avoid specify default property file using i18n Constants

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization

I am making an web app using GWT i18n.

I have an interface which defines

```
public interface MyConstants extends Constants {
    String value();
}
```

and three property files:

```
MyConstants_en.properties
MyConstants_es.properties
MyConstants_de.properties
```

When I compile this code, it gave me error:

```
[INFO]             Processing interface com.mycompany.myproject.client.i18n.MyConstants
[INFO]                Generating method body for value()
[INFO]                   [ERROR] No resource found for key 'value'
```

There are two ways to solve this,

- Add the following line into the GWT module definition ".gwt.xml" file:

  ```
     <set-property name="locale" value="en" />
  ```

However, if I do this, I lost the ability to specify locale using query parameter "&locale=de". My page always stays as English.

- Add an additional property file MyConstants.properties which contains the same contents with 
  MyConstants_en.properties.It works perfectly. However, I don't want to keep both MyConstants.properties and MyConstants_en.properties which have exactly the same contents.

  Is there any way I can:

  1. Use the URL query parameter to control current locale
  2. Without specifying the additional property file
  3. Successfully build it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

GWT comes out of the box configured with what they call the "default" locale which has some very basic localization settings. The default locale is looking for your MyConstants.properties file. If you want your "default" locale to be MyConstants_en.properties then make the following adjustments to your gwt.xml module file.

```
<!-- inherit these modules to activate GWT internationalization -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N' />
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.CldrLocales"/>

<!-- add the various locales you wish to support -->
<extend-property name="locale" values="en"/>
<extend-property name="locale" values="es"/>
<extend-property name="locale" values="de"/>

<!-- instructs the application use this locale when there is no locale specified (i.e. replaces the default) -->
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en" />
```

By setting the "set-property-fallback" to "en" the application will use your MyConstants_en.properties file.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this does not work. I can set the default locale to en using:  <set-property name="locale" value="en" />. But if I do this, I won't be able to change locale from the query string.

Comment: @Kevin I think you misunderstood the example. Don't use <set-property name="locale" value="en"/>. You would be "locking" your locale into "en". My example doesn't do that at all. Instead, by using the "extend-property" you are telling GWT to expand you locale to support to "en,es,de". By setting the "set-property-fallback" you are telling GWT to use the specified locale when there is no locale specified by the browser/query string instead of using the "default" locale (which is the built in one). Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what happened.

I think GWT does something at compile time to make sure a constant always have a default value. The standard way for this is to define a default property file, in my case:

```
MyConstants.properties
```

Even it contains the same value of `MyConstants_en.properties`.

If this file is not presented, we have to tell GWT the default value using the @Defaultxxxxxx annotation.

In my example, I have to provide:

```
@LocalizableResource.DefaultLocale("en")
public interface MyConstants extends Constants {
    @DefaultStringValue("Hello")
    String value();
}
```

And I shall also specify the default locale using @LocalizableResource.DefaultLocale("en") in the Constant interface declaration.

This allows my code compile cleanly without the default property file.